# QApplication (PySide) Django app issue with quitting

Tags: python, django, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a Django app in which the users can create reports at various places throughout the webapp. As a little nifty feature I would like to make a "send as PDF" feature for these reports, and I'm almost there.

What I do is that before the report is returned as a HttpResponse through Django I send the raw HTML content through a small PySide/QT snippet (as seen below).

The problem is that I can't get the QApplication to quit.

I have tried with the standard `QCoreApplication.exit()` but with no luck. If I try to convert a new report right after the first one, the console says a "QApplication instance already exists".

I am using Django 1.2.5, Python 2.7, QT 4.8 and PySide 1.1 on OS X 10.7.3 (for testing).

Code:

```
def makepdf(response,filename):
    try:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    except:
        app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    web = QWebView()

    stylelink = "%s%s" % (media_root,'images/css/reportGenerator.css') 

    web.settings().setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(stylelink))
    web.setHtml(response)

    printer = QPrinter()
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName(filename)

    def convertToPdf():
        web.print_(printer)
        #webresponse = web.close()        
        #QObject.disconnect()
        #print QCoreApplication.instance().children()[0].interrupt()
        #qthread = QCoreApplication.instance().thread()#.cleanup()
        #qthread.exit()
        QCoreApplication.exit()
    QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertToPdf())
```

Code comments:

Currently I have made a `try`/`except` clause to be able to keep the code running, by using the current QApplication instance (to avoid the 'instance exists error'), but this just doesn't seem right?. I mean, having a QAppliation running for the duration of my Apache server (which will be the case in production) seems a bit off. Shouldn't it be possible to quit it after the PDF conversion is done?

Other than the `QCoreApplication.exit()` I have tried to use the `sys.exit(app.exec_())` method, as is often seen in examples and snippets. This however just causes an error and makes Python crash and the code works perfectly without this. (well it creates the PDF, but won't quit).

All the lines commented out are the previous attempts I have made to quit the QApplication.

In short: I don't know what it is, but it just won't quit. Can anyone suggest why?

**Update:** After the latest answer I have edited the code to respond to the input. This is how the final part looks now:

```
def convertToPdf():
    web.print_(printer)
    app.exit()
web.loadFinished.connect(convertToPdf)
app.exec_()
```

I do, however, still get an error:

> 2012-04-30 00:16:10.791 Python[21241:1803] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-833.24/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:324
>   Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

This error only occurs when I implement `app.exec_()`. However without `app.exec_()` it is just the normal issue again, with no quitting.

Any ideas?

**Update 2:** this is the newest code, fixed in accordance with matas latest suggestion:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
def convertToPdf():
    web.print_(printer)
    app.exit()
web.loadFinished.connect(convertToPdf)
web.setHtml(response)
```

I still have the same problem however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PySide is designed such that there is only ever one instance of QCoreApplication within a process.  The best reference to this (possibly undocumented fact) that I could find was http://bugs.pyside.org/show_bug.cgi?id=855.

Basically, there may be dangling references to the qapplication that prevent it from being reaped by the garbage collector, so even if you tell the application to exit *and* you delete your reference, there may still be other references lying around.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks for replying. Do you know whether or not this QApplication process can be contained somehow? In order to move the process away from the main Django/Python process, and then perhabs closing it down manually?

Comment: Ignoring the memory overhead, keeping a QApplication instance around shouldn't cause any problems.  If it was me, I'd just keep the single QApplication instance running.

An alternative would be to make the conversion an external application, but I can't speak to whether there are security risks there or not.  I normally write desktop Qt applications, not web apps.

Answer (score 1):

what i can say is this:

```
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertToPdf())
```

here you **call** `convertToPdf()`, if you want to connect the signal, omit the parenthesis!

you could also use this much clearer syntax:

```
web.loadFinished.connect(convertToPdf)
```

you may also want to add a parameter to convertToPdf, as it is called with a boolean indicating wheather loading was successful or not.

And using `app.exit()` should be enough.

oh, and when you use Gui-Components you need to use a `QApplication`. A `QCoreApplication` won't do!

*edit:* it's important to call `web.setHtml` **after** you've connected the `loadFinished` signal! otherwise if the loading already is finished, your function will never be executed!

*edit*: this works without any problem for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def createPdf(html, filename):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebView()
    printer = QPrinter()
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
    def convertToPdf():
        web.print_(printer)
        app.exit()
        app.deleteLater()
    web.loadFinished.connect(convertToPdf)
    web.setHtml(html)
    app.processEvents()

def createPdfInSubprocess(html, filename):
       p = Popen(["python", __file__, filename], 
                stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
       out, err = p.communicate(html)
       return (p.returncode, out, err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # read html from stdin, filename from cmdline
        html = "\n".join(sys.stdin.readlines())
        createPdf(html, sys.argv[1])
        # print("done")
    else:
        # test if it's working
        ret = createPdfInSubprocess(
                "<html><h1>test</h1>it's working...</html>", "test.pdf")
        print(ret)
```

Even without all the calls to `app.exit()`, `app.deleteLater()`, `app.processEvents()`, it still works... but can't hurt to have that.

One more important thing: QApplications have to be created from the main thread! So if it's running inside a django app it's probably not going to work, that's why i added the subprocess stuff...

Comment: Calling app.exec_() will relinquish control to Qt's event loop, which probably isn't what Peter wants inside his web application.  You can call QApplication.processEvents() to force Qt to process events on the queue.  However, signal handlers are called immediately when connected via signals/slots unless the application is multi-threaded.

Comment: I have changed the code according to your input :)

(I can't seem to paste the changed code in a comment field?? I have pasted it in my first post)

Comment: Thanks Nathan. That could explain the funny error. Do you have any ideas as to how this can be solved??

Or maybe it doesn't matter?? 
Could one simply start the QApplication when the server starts?? And then just use the same QApplication throughout?

Comment: ok, true, `app.exec_()` isn't really what he wants... i think the problem here is that the signal never triggers as setHtml is called before the loadFinished-signal is connected

Comment: Hi again. I have tried the last suggestion and I have posted the new code in the top. The problem still persists though :-/

What happens is that in my OS X Dock, a Python icon (the Python launcher or whatever it is) opens and keeps on "bouncing" in the Dock. So it kinda looks like PySide creates a new thread somewhere? Could this be a solution? 
I meen is it somehow possible to manually create a new thread just for PySide/QApplication, and then keep the whole thing in that thread and closing it down afterwards? 
Giving that i don't want the main Python/Django thread to close...

Comment: and you don't get any error messages? it works for me, at least locally. on a server there could of course be the problem that you need to have an xserver running to create a QApplication (or at least a virtual like [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)).

Comment: I only get the one i've been getting all along(whenever i use app.exec_()):

error: 2012-04-30 00:16:10.791 Python[21241:1803] * Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-833.24/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:324 Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

Besides that i only the the error that a QApplication is already running :-S It's weird is what it is..

Comment: Maybe i should clarify. I'm running everything in Djangos testserver environment, but it would eventually need to run in a Apache/mod_wsgi setup.